# Does the DebuggerDisplay directive ",nq" only have effect for strings?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, debuggerdisplay

I'm writing some code to automatically parse/evaluate `DebuggerDisplay` strings for unit testing purposes. I'm curious, does the `,nq` directive only have effect for strings? I see that if I write

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{c,nq}")]
public class D { public C c = new C(); }

public class C { }
```

Then a `new D()` will present as `{C}` in the debugger. Removing the `,nq` from the display string has the same effect. Only if I change the type of `c` to a string, like this

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{c,nq}")]
public class D { public string c = "foo"; }
```

does removing/keeping `,nq` seem to have effect (it results in `"foo"` and `foo`, respectively). So does `,nq` only matter when you're trying to display a string field/member?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

'nq' literally means 'no quotes' (strip leading quotes from object value). So, yes, only when trying to display string members.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2011/03/18/debuggerdisplay-attribute-best-practices/